# Caption disappears with tabularray

Tags: tables, tabularray

I'm using to `tblr` for tables but whenever I switch the table to fit one column, caption disappears and for the second table it's too wide so I used

```
\newcommand{\spheading}[2][7em]{% \spheading[<width>]{<stuff>}
  \raisebox{-.5\normalbaselineskip}[6pt][1pt]{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{#1}{\raggedright #2}}}}
```

from another post on the Stack to vertically align the text, but for some reason the row's length is shrinking when I used the command. Any ideas would be appreciate it.

```
\documentclass[default,iicol]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{multirow}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\spheading}[2][7em]{% \spheading[<width>]{<stuff>}
  \raisebox{-.5\normalbaselineskip}[6pt][1pt]{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{#1}{\raggedright #2}}}}
\begin{table*}[h!]
    \centering
\begin{tblr}
{
  colspec = {|m{0.09\textwidth}|  % <-- use 'm', not 'p', 
              m{0.13\textwidth}| 
              m{0.04\textwidth}|
              m{0.06\textwidth}|
              m{0.07\textwidth}|
              m{0.05\textwidth}|
              m{0.05\textwidth}|
              m{0.08\textwidth}|
              m{0.06\textwidth}|
              m{0.06\textwidth}|
                },
hline{1,2} = {1pt,solid},
hline{3,4-7,9-12} = {dashed},
hline{4,8,13} = {solid},
row{1} = {gray!30},
 %  cell{4-8,10-16,20-24,28-32,36-40}{2}={c=2}{h,0.6\paperwidth},
  measure=vbox,
  row{1-Z} = {font=\small},
cell{1}{1-3} = {font=\small\bfseries},
%   cell{1,9,17,25,33}{1-2} = {font=\small\bfseries},
} 
&\spheading{Profession}  & \spheading{Student}  & \spheading{Company \& employee} & \spheading{Faculty \& staff} & 
\spheading{Researcher} & \spheading{Self-employed \& freelancers} &  \spheading{Innovative enterprise manager} &  \spheading{Chi-square test} & 
\spheading{Sign. \\ (\%)} \\
\end{tblr}
\caption{yyyyyyyyyyy}
\label{tabVIII}
\end{table*}

\begin{table}[t!]
    \centering
\begin{tblr}
{
  colspec = {|m{0.09\textwidth}|  % <-- use 'm', not 'p', 
              m{0.15\textwidth}| 
              m{0.03\textwidth}|
              m{0.07\textwidth}|
                },
hline{1,2} = {1pt,solid},
hline{3,5-7,9-13,15-18} = {dashed},
hline{4,8,14,19} = {solid},
row{1} = {gray!30},
  measure=vbox,
  row{1-Z} = {font=\small},
cell{1}{1-3} = {font=\small\bfseries},
} 
Item & Classification & No. & Perc. (\%)\\
\end{tblr}
\caption{xxxxxxx.}
\label{tabI}
\end{table}





\Cref{tabI} outlines 
\Cref{tabVIII} outlines 


\end{document}
```

This is an update to the problem, so I used the code provided below and I tried to test it on Overleaf, and I noticed that when I remove the  `row{1}  = {cmd=\rothead,},`, the caption disappears, but when I keep it the caption appears again.

Please check the Overleaf to see the problem. I would appreciate any help since I've been trying to solve the problem since a few days now.

Answer (score 0):

- I can't reproduce your problem. In test I used up-to-date MiKTeX.
- However, at least the first table, as you defined columns widths, is quite wide, so you will have hard time to fit it in one column.
- Your code for column headers with rotate text is a bit clumsy, I suggest to employ `rotating` and `makecell` package as I did in MWWE below.
- It is unknown, what is table content, consequently I cant judged if you really need to define width of each column separately. In MWE below I assume that they can have equal width.

```
\documentclass[default,iicol]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%\usepackage{graphicx}  % not used in MWE
%\usepackage{multirow}  %
%\usepackage{amssymb}   %
%\usepackage{amsthm}    %
%\usepackage{mathrsfs}  %
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath, varwidth}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cleveref}
%\usepackage{float}     % not recommended 

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
    \begin{table}[ht]%{sidewaystable}
\renewcommand\theadfont{}
\settowidth\rotheadsize{Faculty \& staff}    % from makecell
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,2} = {1pt,solid},
             hline{3,4-7,9-12} = {dashed},
             hline{4,8,13} = {solid},
             vlines,
             colspec = {Q[c,m]  
                        *{9}{X[c,m]}},
             row{1}  = {cmd=\rothead, bg=gray!30, rowsep=0pt},
             measure=vbox,
             row{1-Z} = {font=\small},
             cell{1}{1-3} = {font=\small\bfseries},
             colsep = 1pt,
%   cell{4-8,10-16,20-24,28-32,36-40}{2}={c=2}{h,0.6\paperwidth},
%   cell{1,9,17,25,33}{1-2} = {font=\small\bfseries},
            }
    & Profession
        & Student
            & Company \& employee
                & Faculty \& staff
                    & Researcher
                        & Self-employed \& freelancers
                            & Innovative enterprise manager
                                & Chi-square test
                                    & Sign. (\%)            \\
1   & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 7 & 8 & 9                     \\            
\end{tblr}
\caption{yyyyyyyyyyy}
\label{tabVIII}
\end{table}

\Cref{tabVIII} outlines \dots

\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm actually using Overleaf, here is the link that shows the Caption problem https://www.overleaf.com/5771377539zjynpsfsgdst

Comment: @Diana, your example in Overleaf generate bunch (8) of errors and no result. If insert my MWE there I get the same result as I shown in my answer (with 6 warnings which are not related to tables and captions). You should first resolve problems related to used document class. The same errors are happen if content of your document replace by some dummy text. Since I'm not familiar with this document class, I can't help you in this.

Comment: It seems from another posts, the problem appears only with the new version of the class, so anyone knows how can I get the old version

Comment: @Diana, ask Overleaf team for help in resolving your problem. I test my MWE in Overleaf and it works fine.

Comment: Please check the updated Overleaf link to see the problem, I don't Overleaf can help since I'm running the same using MikteX and I'm getting the same problem again